# Problems by using cURL from PHP for scraping source code

Tags: javascript, php, curl

i try to automate a download from a HTML-datasheet to generate a customized reporting. The following i was doing with CURL:

```
// init cURL HTTP Client 
$header = array(); 
$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"; 
$header[] = "Pragma: "; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/.cookies'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  '/.cookies'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 600); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https:// ... /signin.html'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=".$login."&password=".$pass); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

The login works fine and i can get many pages without any problems. Now i try to get the datasheet by the following:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https:// ... /data.html'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ''); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

But now i get the following answer:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language='javascript'>function autoNavigate() {window.location="/data.html";}</script>
</head>
<body onload='autoNavigate()'></body>
</html>
```

The javaScript call refresh the same page as i loaded before. In a browser it works fine, but if i load the same page again with "curl_exec($ch)" i've got a 302-error?

Is there a possibilty the refresh the page with curl without a full reload? Or any other idea to get the content of the page?

Thanks

Comment: 302 isn't an error, it's a redirect code. Do you have `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` set in the second `curl` call?

Comment: I dont change `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` in the second call. Yes, 302 isnt an error, but it redirects to an error page.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$postfields = '';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https:// ... /data.html'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

It creates problem when you set false the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS value but earlier you set it as True bacause it holds the previous details in Cookie.

I hope this will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the link of data.html?
If the data.html in `window.location="data.html";` is the same location of data.html in `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https:// ... /data.html');`  try to double `curl_exec($ch)` so may be it needs to access two times. Or if it different, just simple change your link.

Comment: Yes, i check it. It is the same link. Only difference the first one is a url with "https:// ... /" (absolute) and the url in the javascript is without (relative). But it is always the same.

Comment: If that, may be you need to exec curl 2 times, and if need set the referer also like this:<br/>
`curl_exec($ch);<br/>
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://..../data.html');<br/>
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
`

Comment: A double "curl_exec($ch)" results also a 302-error.

Comment: Ok, first HTTP 302 is not an error. It's redirect code. Try to show the header of response then get the location in the header and change url to the new location. Like this:
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);` in the $response you will see something like this: `Location: https://.../newlink.html`
Use this new location to get your page. This because some host not allow `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` options.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to explain that the 302 is not an error, but a redirection to an error page. Here a part of the Header:

`HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: private
Location: https:// ... /reportingError.html
Content-Type: text/html;charset=windows-1252
Content-Length: 0
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C9CFFE27F202765BC562274539CA11F5; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Vary: User-Agent`

Comment: If that, may be this case more complex. May be you not login completely successful or miss something when get the data.html. You may need use some sniff tools to check how website do to get the data.html page then replay in by your PHP code. I suggest you use Fiddler to analyse it.